# Compute the radius of convergence and interval of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left (\frac {4+2(-1)^n} 5\right)^nx^n $

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Compute the radius and interval of convergence of:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac {4+2(-1)^n} 5\right)^nx^n  .$$

I went about this question by applying the root test and this is what I have gotten so far:

$$\lim_{n \to\infty}\left(\left(\frac {4+2(-1)^n} 5\right)^n\right)^\frac1n \left(x^n\right)^\frac1n \\
=\lim_{n \to\infty}\frac {4+2(-1)^n} 5x \\
=x\lim_{n \to\infty}\frac {4+2(-1)^n} 5 \\
=\begin{cases}\frac25x & \text{when $n$ is odd}\\
\frac65x & \text{when $n$ is even}\end{cases}$$
Am I going in the right way? If so how do I progress?

Comment: Is $[\cdot]$ supposed to be a floor/ceiling function, or are they simply brackets?

Comment: Remember that the root test uses $\limsup$.

Comment: Or try: $\lim {a_{n}/a_{n+1}}$

Comment: @gebruiker They are supposed to be just brackets